# Website performance is poor except on Chrome

Tags: html, css, performance, lag

I have created this personal website: [www.lonewulf.eu](http://lonewulf.eu), but I am getting poor performance in the following browsers:

Performance:

Chrome - Good(as it should)

Firefox - Good(a bit slower than Chrome)

IE 9 - Medium/Slow

Opera - Extra slow/laggy

Now, I do have a lot of flash overlays(3 flash files) and a portfolio showcase on the same page which doesn't help but even if I remove those it still lags. It seems to be a css issue, any suggestions on this?

CSS: http://www.lonewulf.eu/css/main.css

Comment: I can't load the website in chrome here. Why using flash? in 2013?...

Comment: Here's the css: http://www.lonewulf.eu/css/main.css. If the site is not loading try in a second, the server might be down. Also why use Flash? because I can't achieve the effects I am using with HTML5.

Comment: Why the downvote? because your website isn't loading at all.

Comment: Did you read my comment? The server might have gone down...a little patience?

Comment: It's already working now. It's slow in Chrome too.

Comment: Could you tell us which effects you use with flash?

Comment: What do you mean by effects? It's simple animations, the clouds/eyes and moon. You guys comment on flash while I mentioned that even if I remove these it still perfroms badly.

Comment: No slow here but could be faster. Use audits in Chrome to detect your problem(s)

Comment: Here's the audits report, one yellow: `Remove unused CSS rules (96)
96 rules (53%) of CSS not used by the current page.
main.css: 4% is not used by the current page.
jquery.fancybox.css: 92% is not used by the current page.
stapel.css: 13% is not used by the current page.
custom.css: 68% is not used by the current page.
Inline block #1: 100% is not used by the current page.
form.css: 75% is not used by the current page.
Inline block #2: 100% is not used by the current page.`

Answer (score 1):

Taking some stabs in the dark (no IE here atm), I see a few potential issues:

- You're using web fonts extensively; for older browsers, this can have a sizeable performance impact;
- You seem to set up a bunch of incomplete css transitions; you define how long the transition is, and what the transition function is, but you never specify which property you want to transition.
- You appear to be loading jQuery twice.

Comment: I removed the font-face and all the transitions on localhost but it didn't help with the performance. Also removed the second jquery load, thanks.